# I need this boolean to give me the lowest card value and print the first lowest card. When i use this method, it gives me the last card value

Tags: java, boolean, poker

```
public String lowCard() {
    if (card1.getValue() < card2.getValue() && 
            card1.getValue() <card3.getValue() &&
            card1.getValue() < card4.getValue()) {
        return new string (card1.toString());
    }
    
    else (card2.getValue() < card1.getValue() &&
            card2.getValue() < card3.getValue() &&
            card2.getValue() < card4.getValue()) {
        return (card2.toString());
    }
    
    else (card3.getValue() < card1.getValue() &&
            card3.getValue() < card2.getValue() &&
            card3.getValue() < card4.getValue()) {
        return (card3.toString());
    }
    else
        return (card4.toString());
}
```

It should print..
3 of clubs
2 of diamonds
5 of clubs
2 of clubs
The low card is 2 of diamonds

but it prints...
3 of clubs
2 of diamonds
5 of clubs
2 of clubs
The low card is 2 of clubs

Comment: Where are these values coming from? String arrays? How are they set? You also cant have two elses like this.

Comment: I don't think it prints anything, since this code won't even compile.

Comment: There is more code, the card values are stored as integers further up but I didn’t include that into the question. The app class has the printlns and use of the method.

Comment: These are very important things to add for debugging. You need to show what type the values are. You need to show something you've actually ran and compiled (bc this 100% does not compile). How are these integers if it's `int` of clubs/diamonds? An int cant store all that info, so how are you creating these cards?

Comment: I added the entire code below as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few things happening here that we can make better.

1. This code as written does not compile. We can't have 2 `else`s after an `if`. `else` should be the last in the decision tree with no conditions. When we do `if/else if/else` statements the syntax looks like this:

   ```
   if(condition){
      //do something 
   } else if (condition) {
      //do something
   } else {
     //do something
   }
   ```

Notice the placement of your current braces do not match this syntax.

2. With that in mind, you need `else if`s and you mentioned in a comment that these are integers. So we should change how we return it if we want a string value. We can do `String.valueOf(num)` or `Integer.toString(num)` It'll look like this:

   ```
   public String lowCard() {
    if ((card1 < card2) && 
        (card1 < card3) &&
        (card1 < card4)) 
    {
        return Integer.toString(card1);
    }

    else if ((card2 < card1) && 
             (card2 < card3) &&
             (card2 < card4))  
    {
        return  Integer.toString(card2);
    }

    else if ((card3 < card1) && 
             (card3 < card2) &&
             (card3 < card4))  
    {
        return  Integer.toString(card3);
    }
    else
        return  Integer.toString(card4);
    }
   ```

Now remember that these cards HAVE to be global variables because you haven't passed them into your function. As for where it says "of clubs" or "of diamonds" you got me. That's not listed in the question anywhere. If you complete your question, I can complete this answer.